# c++ storing a cin value into an array of any type

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

Hi this is my first post; but not my first time on this site; I tried finding an answer to my problem but so far I can't quite find it.

What I have at the moment is a template class for an Array

```
template<typename T, int size>
class Array{

//Leaving out all my other stuff because I don't thinks its relevant.

private:

T array[size];
}
```

Now what I need to do is read one single line from cin into the array such as

```
>>enter values: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and store them in array as [1][2][3][4]...etc
OR

```
>>Enter values: Hello world!
```

and store them in array as [Hello][World!]

Most people asking this are entering them in separately like

```
>>Enter values: 1
2
3
4
5
etc.
```

But that's not what I need and I'm not sure how to split it up.
My attempt:

```
template <typename T, int size>
void Array<T, size>::inputArray() {

    T data;
    getline(cin,data);
    istringstream elements (data);
    dynamicArray = elements;
}
```

But this comes with a whole mess of errors.

Comment: Did you try a `for` loop together with the `>>` operator?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried using a for loop earlier and cin to read in values. But the problem with that was I would have to enter for it to store. Asuming you mean this:
```
for(int i =0 i < size; ++i){
     cin >> array[i];
}
```

Comment: You have press "Enter" no matter how you read from `std::cin`. That's how C++ works on all general-purpose operating systems.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "*You have press "Enter" no matter how you read from `std::cin`*" - not always.

Comment: Ok, you can also press `CTRL-D` or `CTRL-Z`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::getline()` reads into a `std::string`, you can't have it read directly into a `T[]` array like you are trying to do.

However, since you already know the max number of elements to expect (from your `size` template argument), you can simply call `operator>>` in a loop to parse formatted array elements from the `std::istringstream` that you populate from `std::cin` data, eg:

```
template <typename T, int size>
void Array<T, size>::inputArray() {
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    istringstream iss(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (!(iss >> array[i])) {
            // eof or error, handle as needed...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/zBbtJ5)

Comment: I forgot an #include statement XD Your solution works Thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 0):

Use loop for input or if you want to take input once then split that integer using divide and modulus operator. Store each new integer in array index and increment the index.

Comment: "*split that integer using divide and modulus operator*" - That won't work for non-integer input.